# show keyboard programmatically Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Is there a way to show keyboard in an Activity above Android O version ? I have the following code :

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

It works 'only' for below Android O Version.

Answer (score 7):

I got 2 options for you. First, you can use RequestFocus

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

Second, you can execute this code to show the keyboard for a specific EditText

```
android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager imm = (android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(editText, android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Extra point, use this to hide the keyboard:

```
android.view.View view = this.getCurrentFocus();   
android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager imm = (android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Note: every code here is tested and working.

Answer (score 1):

To show keyboard,

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

If you want to focus to a editText, use

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

To hide keyboard,

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: this is depreacted

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin method to show keyboard

Now toogleSoftInput is deprecated.

```
 private fun showKeyboard() {
            val imm: InputMethodManager =
                 context?.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as 
       InputMethodManager
         imm.showSoftInput(binding.yourEditText, 0)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For **kotlin** `extension` function and reusable

```
fun View.hideKeyboard() {
    ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(this)?.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
}

fun View.showKeyboard() {
    ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(this)?.show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
}

fun View.showKeyboardAndFocus() {
    ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(this)?.show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
    requestFocus()
}
```